# Compare two datetime values with c# one from table and other is the current

Tags: c#

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ExitTime,EnterTime,name,[tag-id-st],[build-id],[room-no],tagType FROM Students,GateLogging WHERE GateLogging.tagType='student'", MyConn);
DateTime ss=dt.Rows[0][1];       
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
int x=date.CompareTo(ss);
```

This is my code, I stopped here and I can't complete

Please help me to compare the values in "EnterTime" table with the current time and show in gridview the values that is more than the current time with 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

First, find the date you actually care about - for example it might be

```
DateTime cutoff = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
```

(do this once at the top, rather than per row) - then just compare against those, for example:

```
bool isOverdue = ss > cutoff;
```

You can also do this inside the database with `GETDATE()` and `DATEADD(...)` or `DATEDIFF(...)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can change the select query to return only rows for a last 10 minutes, and you will not need to compare, Second you can use da.Fill(dt) to copy resultset to datatable and use dt.Select("...") to filter only your rows, and the third what is the problem? you can write

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (now - ss <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same problem in unit testing I wrote an AssertEx class with some less nitpicky assertions:

```
public static void AreSimilar(DateTime expected, DateTime actual, TimeSpan tolerance, string message)
{
    DateTime expectedMin = expected.Subtract(tolerance);
    DateTime expectedMax = expected.Add(tolerance);

    if (actual < expectedMin || actual > expectedMax)
    {
        throw new AssertFailedException(message);
    }
}
```